# MySql single column index or multi-column index in this case

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-like

I have the following simplified table `'places'`, which contains 200,000+ rows:

```
placeId INT(10)
placeName VARCHAR (30)
placeNameEnglish VARCHAR (30)
```

- `placeName` is a place name stored in the original language e.g. **Rhône**
- `placeNameEnglish` is a place name translated into english e.g. **Rhone**

Currently I have two single column indexes - one for `placeName` and one for `placeNameEnglish` and am conducting these `LIKE` pattern queries:

`$testStr = 'rho';`

```
SELECT placeId
FROM places
WHERE (placeName LIKE '$testStr%' OR placeNameEnglish LIKE '$testStr%')
```

Done some research but can't quite get my head around multi-column indexes when used in this scenario. Question is, should I combine `placeName` and `placeNameEnglish` into a multi-column index or leave them as separate indexes?

## UPDATE

Working on implementing the last suggested by @Gordon Linoff.

Considering adding a table named `translations` instead of `placeNames`so that the same index can be used for multiple tables  i.e a `persons` table that requires the same `LIKE 'abc%'` matching.

So far:

`transId INT`

`parentId INT` - either `placeId` or `personId`

`parentTypeId TINYINT` - either `1` to identify the `places` table or `2` for the `persons` table, etc (more tables could use this system at a later date)

`languageId INT`

`transName VARCHAR`

Should I also index the `parentTypeId` to accommodate the extra `WHERE` condition required to identify the correct parent table?

e.g. `WHERE transName LIKE 'abc%' AND parentTypeId = 1`

I imagine mysql works like this: it first uses the index for `transName` to match against `transName LIKE 'abc%'`, then it filters the results using `parentTypeId = 1`

Comment: Please review the answers.

Comment: I'm torn on which of the two options provided will yield the best results. Might try both and run EXPLAIN to benchmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT placeId
FROM places
WHERE placeName LIKE '$testStr%' OR placeNameEnglish LIKE '$testStr%';
```

MySQL *could* use two indexes, one on `places(placeName)` and one on `places(placeNameEnglish)`.  The operation is a called index merge (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html)).  I wouldn't count on it.  This query cannot fully use a composite index.

You can rephrase the query as:

```
SELECT placeId
FROM places
WHERE placeName LIKE '$testStr%'
UNION
SELECT placeId
FROM places
WHERE placeNameEnglish LIKE '$testStr%';
```

or:

```
SELECT placeId
FROM places
WHERE placeName LIKE '$testStr%'
UNION ALL
SELECT placeId
FROM places
WHERE placeId NOT IN (SELECT placeId FROM places WHERE placename LIKE '$testStr%') AND
      placeNameEnglish LIKE '$testStr%';
```

These can take advantage of the two indexes.

My recommendation, though, is to change the structure of your data.  Have a table called `PlaceNames` (or something like that) with these columns:

```
placeNameId INT
placeId INT,
languageId INT,
placeName VARCHAR(255)
```

That is, have a separate row for each language.  Your query can then easily take advantage of an index on `placeName(placeName)`.

Comment: The last option looks interesting and doable in my case. I'm just debating what would happen in the `placeName` table if there were duplicate `placeNames`, although perhaps the inclusion of `placeId` would remedy that problem when the `INNER JOIN` is required to identify the corresponding row in the `places table`.

Comment: Although in this case a multi-column index would appear to also work, I've gone with implementing a new `places` table as this seems to provide a lot of flexibility for managing search terms throughout the site where needed. In addition to the above I added a `placeTypeId` field to identify the `placeId` table source. So search term queries now use the following: `WHERE placeName LIKE 'search term%' AND placeTypeId = 2`. Thanks for all your suggestions, it's been informative.

Answer (score 0):

For your original question:  Two separate INDEXes.  But... You are working too hard:

For European place names, you don't need to search both columns.  The case folding and accent insensitivity of `utf8_unicode_ci` (or virtually any collation other than `utf8_bin`) will do what you need:

```
mysql> SELECT 'Rhône' LIKE '%rho%', 'Rhône' LIKE '%xyz%';
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| 'Rhône' LIKE '%rho%'  | 'Rhône' LIKE '%xyz%'  |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|                     1 |                     0 |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

**Edit** Based on OP's comment, this is not a complete solution.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about utf8. But I should have mentioned, the English column is for the English interpretation. This allows for users typing either the European word or the English interpretation to find the same record. So both columns would be needed e.g. Valle d’Aosta (Italian way) and Aosta Valley (English way)

Comment: Similar things can be said for `CHARACTER SET latin1`, but that handles only Western European languages.

Comment: Given two ways of phrasing a place, my solution is not sufficient.  Still you may want to take advantage of accent stripping if the users are sloppy.